# Is it normal to use AsynTask in viewHolder in CustomAdapter

Tags: android, adapter

I have custom adapter (one image, 2 text fields), and I need to check image inside viewHolder. When image is already exist, show that image in ImageView and when image isn't exist, I need to check connection, if all good, show progressbar, download image, and show it, and if all bad then show default image. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Are you asking how to do it, or whether you should do this or not?

Comment: I know how to do it, but is it correct solution? or I should to check image outside ViewHolder, I worry about memory, because in list there are more 300 items.

Comment: Use Picasso or Glide to load images inside adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you should not implement a Async Task inside ViewHolder bcoz you do not know how much time it will take to load images and the user will be pissed at waiting for the listview to come up.

There are lot of tutorials out there you should use **lazy loading** for images if you are using URLS for images if there are not much images then you can store it in database or in a file and show any time in the listview

Hope it Helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen many people using, it is normal for small operations.

but it can't be used for tasks which take time - as the user experience is affected by lagging.

for small operations you can use it.

Comment: I have a list of 300 items. All 300 would have already pictures, but if the server will increase the number of items. I'll have to download a picture to each of the items added